# How do I get a list of all site features in Sharepoint online using Javascript. I need to display both the Guids and feature name

Tags: sharepoint, office365

Currently an only getting active feature using this code snippet:

```
var featureCollection;
var oneFeature;

var site;
function runCode() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    site = clientContext.get_web();

    clientContext.load(site);

    featureCollection = site.get_features();
    clientContext.load(featureCollection);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var listEnumerator = featureCollection.getEnumerator();
    var featureInfo = [];
```

//I would want to get the feature name in the following block of code

```
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        oneFeature = listEnumerator.get_current();


        featureInfo.push(oneFeature.get_definitionId());

    }
    console.log(featureInfo);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar but apparently there is no way of getting the name of the features, according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247054.aspx) the only property available within an SP.Feature object is the **definitionId**